How to assign an integer value to a Macro in trace32 cmm script?
I have written one file1.cmm file, in this file many
&BITPOS=21
is present.
For example,
&BITPOS=21 &BITPOS=22 &BITPOS=23
and so on present in file1.cmm
I debugged this issue and found form PMACRO window, I observe it is taking
&BITPOS=21
as
&BITPOS=0x21
so when I am trying to shift
1<<&BITPOS
instead of shifting 21 times left shift of 1, it is shifting 0x21 times which is 33 in integer value.
reference:- repo.lauterbach.com/manual.html
Almost all documents I opened but not found any info.

In TRACE32, decimal numbers are declared by adding a decimal point to the number:
&BITPOS=21.

